# how to create a loop in python tkinter but not making gui freeze

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, tkinter, freeze

I tried to create a loop in a tkinter gui.

I've known that tkinter mainloop would run in main thread, so i need to use another thread to run the loop.

however, i still meet the freezing problem.

I think it's because i call the `window.after()` in the loop.

So I would like to know is there anyway to stop the program for a few seconds but not using `after()` .

Btw, i've tried `time.sleep()`, too. The gui still freezing.

Below is my code. Any suggestion would be good.

My question is in `device.run()` and `device.loop()`

Thanks for any help that can be provide.

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import time
import pyfirmata2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from threading import Thread


def COMports():
    COMlist = []
    COMname = []
    ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    for port in ports:
        COMname.append(port.description)
        COMlist.append(port.device)
    #print(COMlist)
    #print(COMname)
    return COMlist, COMname

class device():
    def __init__(self):
        self.baud_rates = 9600
        self.pin = 11
        self.board = []
        self.running = False
        
    def connect(self):
        self.com_uno = self.comVar.get()
        #print(com_uno)  // output: Arduino Uno (COM4)
        self.com = []
        self.com = [i for i in self.comlist if i in self.com_uno]
        self.board = pyfirmata2.Arduino(str(self.com[0]))
        self.pin = self.board.get_pin('d:11:p')
        #print(board)
        window.after(3000)
        print("Device has connected.")
        
    def disconnect(self):
        self.board.exit()
        print("Device has deconnected.")
        
    def off(self):
        try:
            self.pin
            print("pin turning off...")
            self.running = False
            self.pin.write(0)
            #self.board.exit()
        except:
            print("No pin defined")
            #self.board.exit()
        #print("Device has deconnected.")
        
    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        self.volt_base_use = float(self.volt_base.get())
        self.volt_max_use = int(self.volt_max.get())
        self.delays_use = int(self.delay.get())
        self.timer_use = int(self.times.get())
        self.mode_use = self.modeVar.get()
        print("Base volt(V): "+str(self.volt_base_use))
        print("Max volt(V): "+str(self.volt_max_use))
        print("Delays(ms): "+str(self.delays_use))
        print("Timer(s): "+str(self.timer_use))
        #print(self.mode_use)
        match(self.mode_use):
            case (1):
                print("Fixed intensity output")
                if self.delays_use == 0:
                    self.pin.write(self.volt_base_use)
                else:
                    Thread(target = self.loop(self.delays_use))
                if self.timer_use == 0:
                    print("Click stop if u want to stop.")
                else:
                    print(str(self.timer_use))
                    time.sleep(self.timer_use*1000)
                    #window.after(self.timer_use*1000)
                    self.pin.write(0)
            case (2):
                print("Wave mode")
                sig = self.waveform()
                Thread(target = self.wavewrite(sig))
                
    def scanning(self):
        if self.running:
            print(self.running)
        window.after(1000, self.scanning)
        
    def loop(self, delay):
        window.after(delay, self.pin.write(self.volt_base_use))
        window.after(1000, self.pin.write(0))
        window.after(1, self.loop(delay))
                
    def waveform(self):
        self.fs_use = int(self.fs.get())
        print(self.fs_use)
        self.A = self.volt_max_use - self.volt_base_use
        print(self.A)
        self.t = np.arange(0,1,0.001)
        sig = self.A * np.sin(2*3.14*self.fs_use*self.t)+self.volt_base_use
        sig[sig>5] = 5
        sig[sig<0] = 0
        plt.plot(sig)
        return sig
        
    def wavewrite(self, sig):
        while self.running:
            for i in sig:
                self.pin.write(i)
                window.after(1)
    
    def main(self):
        global window
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title('vibration_v1')
        window.geometry('400x400')

        Device.comlist, comname = COMports()
        self.comVar = tk.StringVar()
        label_com = tk.Label(window, text="COM Port")
        label_com.place(x=30, y=25)
        #comVar.set(comname[0])
        menu_com = tk.OptionMenu(window, self.comVar, *comname)
        menu_com.place(x=130, y=20)
        btn_connect = tk.Button(window, text="連接", height=2, width=5, command=self.connect)
        btn_connect.place(x=330, y=22.5)
        btn_connect = tk.Button(window, text="取消連接", height=2, width=7, command=self.disconnect)
        btn_connect.place(x=330, y=75)

        self.modeVar = tk.IntVar()
        self.modeVar.set(1)
        mode1 = tk.Radiobutton(text="Fixed mode", variable=self.modeVar, value=1)
        mode1.place(x=30, y=50)
        mode2 = tk.Radiobutton(text="Wave mode", variable=self.modeVar, value=2)
        mode2.place(x=210, y=50)
        # Base volt
        label_Vbase = tk.Label(window, text="Base Intensity(V):")
        label_Vbase.place(x=30, y=75)
        self.volt_base = tk.StringVar()
        self.volt_base.set(0)
        entry_Vbase = tk.Entry(window, width=5, textvariable=self.volt_base)
        entry_Vbase.place(x=130, y=75)
        # Max volt
        label_Vmax = tk.Label(window, text="Max Intensity(V):")
        label_Vmax.place(x=30, y=100)
        self.volt_max = tk.StringVar()
        self.volt_max.set(0)
        entry_Vmax = tk.Entry(window, width=5, textvariable=self.volt_max)
        entry_Vmax.place(x=130, y=100)
        # Times
        label_time = tk.Label(window, text="Times(s):")
        label_time.place(x=50, y=125)
        self.times = tk.StringVar()
        self.times.set(0)
        entry_time = tk.Entry(window, width=5, textvariable=self.times)
        entry_time.place(x=130, y=125)
        # Wave freq
        label_fs = tk.Label(window, text="Signal freq(Hz):")
        label_fs.place(x=180, y=100)
        self.fs = tk.StringVar()
        self.fs.set(0)
        entry_fs = tk.Entry(window, width=5, textvariable=self.fs)
        entry_fs.place(x=270, y=100)
        # Delay
        label_delay = tk.Label(window, text="Delay(ms):")
        label_delay.place(x=180, y=75)
        self.delay = tk.StringVar()
        self.delay.set(0)
        entry_delay = tk.Entry(window, width=5, textvariable=self.delay)
        entry_delay.place(x=270, y=75)

        btn_on = tk.Button(window, text="啟動", height=2, width=10, command=self.run)
        btn_on.place(x=80, y=350)
        btn_off = tk.Button(window, text="停止", height=2, width=10, command=self.off)
        btn_off.place(x=240, y=350)
        
        window.after(1000, self.scanning)
        window.mainloop()

Device = device()
Device.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because you used `window.after()` in the `device.loop()`.

Try changing to `time.sleep()` and use it in a separate thread:

```
def loop(self, delay):
    while self.running:
        self.pin.write(self.volt_base_use)
        time.sleep(delay/1000)
        self.pin.write(0)
        time.sleep(1)
```

You can start a new thread like this:

```
Thread(target=self.loop, args=(self.delays_use,)).start()
```

Comment: OMG, u save my day!! It works, i've spent lots of time on it. Thank u Bryce!